# NullPointerException while retrieving image form camera activity

Tags: java, android

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

While Trying to save my image from Camera activity from here i am getting the following error at the last line of the function i.e. `imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);`

```
11-03 03:27:21.928: E/AndroidRuntime(27303): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 03:27:21.928: E/AndroidRuntime(27303):    at com.example.echelon.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:37)
11-03 03:27:21.928: E/AndroidRuntime(27303):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
11-03 03:27:21.928: E/AndroidRuntime(27303):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3443)
11-03 03:27:21.928: E/AndroidRuntime(27303):    ... 11 more
```

To make sure on my sid ethrough debug i have make sure that the `photo` is not null and contains data and shows this in the object description: `android.graphics.Bitmap@414b2518`

I have also find on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity) that there is a bug in Samsung devices, if the bug is related to samsung OS than i am not actually using one, I am using `Cyanogen Mod` in a Samsung device.
can someone please help me out here?

Comment: are you sure that your imageView is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that the image is correctly been retrieved from camera, but your `imageView` object is null. You should do somewhere before accessing it something like this.-

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageId);
```

Also, make sure you're not *shadowing* the instance variable `imageView` redefining it in another method (such as `onCreate`) like this.-

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageId);
```